# Line breaks in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, replace, line-breaks

I have an address Field in my SSRS report that displays as below

```
PARADISE BALTI
104
WHITWORTH ROAD
ROCHDALE
LANCASHIRE
OL12 0JJ
```

How do I format this so it all appears on one line?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to write expression and concatenate string like

```
=First(Fields!Name.Value, "DataSet")  +  "<br/>" + First(Fields!Address1.Value, "DataSet") +  "<br/>" + First(Fields!City.Value, "DataSet") + ", " + First(Fields!State.Value, "DataSet") + " " + First(Fields!Zip.Value, "DataSet")
```

Take a text box and create a placeholder and set value as an expression shown above.. Then choose markerup type as HTML ...